# Node memory leak issue

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

We are facing an issue of memory leak in node application(**node 12.14**). The issue is only reproduced in node version 12.14 or above. A memory leak doesn't found when the node version is downgraded to **8.10**. CPU usage is also increasing with the memory. I am sharing graph usage for more information.

**Node version- 12.14**

[image: Node version 12.14]

**Node version- 8.10**

[image]

Comment: I found this article interesting just try those steps: https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/debugging-memory-leaks-node-js-applications

Comment: And, what do you expect us to do with this information?  There's no code to look at.  There's no heap diagnostics to look at.  All I can really say is to read about how to debug memory leaks and go collect a bunch of that information and then, if the problem isn't obvious to you by then, come back here and post all your diagnostic information.  It sounds like you just need to read 3-4 articles about tracking down memory leaks in node.js and start gathering relevant diagnostic info so you can find out what part of your code is doing this.